QGIS TIFF load error
I'm working on detecting the saturation of an image with a spatial resolution of 5m,
x size : 17287 y size : 12155 by using c++ code.
Of the more than 200 million pixels in total, 60 pixels were detected. The detected pixels were set to a dn value of 1, and the non-pixels were set to a dn value of 0.
After that, when the TIFF file was retrieved through qgis, all DN values were set to 0.
I'm sure there are about 60 pixels with a DN value of 1.
Experimentally, I increased the number of pixels with a DN value of 1, and in this case, pixels with a DN value of 1 were loaded on QGIS.
Can an error occur if QGIS fetches a TIFF file when only very small pixels have different DN values compared to the total number of pixels?


const std::string kFormat = "GTiff";
GDALDriver* gdal_driver = NULL;

gdal_driver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(kFormat.c_str());

if (gdal_driver != NULL) {

    GDALDataType gdal_data_type;

    if (std::is_same<Tp_, double>::value) {
        gdal_data_type = GDT_Float64;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<Tp_, float>::value) {
        gdal_data_type = GDT_Float32;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<Tp_, unsigned int>::value) {
        gdal_data_type = GDT_UInt32;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<Tp_, unsigned short>::value) {
        gdal_data_type = GDT_UInt16;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<Tp_, udm::byte8_t>::value) {
        gdal_data_type = GDT_Byte;
    }
    else {
        gdal_data_type = GDT_Unknown;
    }

    GDALDataset* gdal_dataset = NULL;
    gdal_dataset = gdal_driver->Create(image_file_path.c_str(), cols, rows, 1, gdal_data_type, NULL);

    if ((NULL != gdal_dataset) && (nullptr != image_data)) {

        if (false == wkt.empty()) {
            gdal_dataset->SetProjection(wkt.c_str());
        }

        if (nullptr != geo_transform) {
            gdal_dataset->SetGeoTransform(geo_transform);
        }

        GDALRasterBand* gdal_raster_band = gdal_dataset->GetRasterBand(1);
        if (CE_Failure == gdal_raster_band->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, 0, cols, rows, image_data, cols, rows, gdal_data_type, 0, 0)) {
            rtn = false;
            std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << " line#" << __LINE__ << " [ERROR] Access fails." << std::endl;
        }
            GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)gdal_dataset);
        }
        else {
            rtn = false;
            std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << " line#" << __LINE__ << " [ERROR] Fail to create mask file." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        rtn = false;
        std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << " line#" << __LINE__ << " [ERROR] Loading GTiff Driver." << std::endl;

    }//end of if ~ else clause
    return rtn;
}


How are you judging this in qgis? Visually or with raster statistics?
